# Laravel 8 - Trusted Proxies. Confused between 'fideloper/TrustedProxy' and 'TrustProxies Middleware'

Tags: php, proxy, package, laravel-8, trusted

I need to implement Trusted Proxy but I'm confused between the PHP package `fideloper/TrustedProxy` (https://github.com/fideloper/TrustedProxy) and the `app/Http/Middleware/TrustedProxies.php` Middleware (https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/requests#configuring-trusted-proxies)

I notice that the `fideloper/TrustedProxy` package is in the `composer.json`; but can I use just one? Are they redundant?

Thank you for the clarification

Comment: For Laravel 8, you only set the proxies in the middleware that you referenced, as documented here: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/requests#configuring-trusted-proxies . You don't need to add/remove a package.